# CodeIgniter2 error from cli

Tags: php, command-line, cron, codeigniter-2

I have created a CodeIgniter controller to run it from command line. I am running Codeigniter v2.

When I run controller from command line it gives me below error.

php index.php updateBalance update_sms_balance
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class CI_Exceptions in /home/praj/app/testweb/system/libraries/Exceptions.php on line 27

I want to set above command to cronjob.

I have few constants defined in config.php file but from command line it gives me an error that constant already defined.

How can I solve this issue? 
I cannot update codeigniter version as its an very big project and client would not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this occurs more than once in your codebase:
`class CI_Exceptions`

If there is more than one match, then there may be a class that is supposed to extend the core `CI_Exceptions` class but doing it incorrectly. The correct syntax for that would be:
`class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions`

If there is only one match, then try adding this to the top of Exceptions.php to find out what code is calling it twice:

```
if(php_sapi_name() === 'cli') debug_print_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
```